# Datatype evaluation in Excel to ASP.NET copy/paste operation

Tags: asp.net, excel, internationalization, clipboard

I think the answer to my question may be that it is not possible, but I am working on a multinational ASP.NET application where users will want to copy a column of numbers from out of an Excel worksheet and into a web GridView. This could be from any client operating system and we want to avoid any client plug-ins, etc.

The problem is that in many countries, number delimiters for decimal and thousands portions are completely reversed. For instance, in Germany a value of 999.999.999,999 translates in the USA to 999,999,999.999. For the raw text "999,999" without knowledge of a format and/or location number preference, it is not know whether that should be (in USA format) 999,999.000 or 999.999.

As far as I have been able to ascertain, in the copy/paste operations from an OS clipboard into a web page, there is no way to also transfer the underlying original Excel data and datatype, e.g., a number represented without these textual delimiters. The only way the data is transmitted is though the formatted text.

Anyone know otherwise or can offer helpful advise?